# How do I use regex curly braces in SublimeText2

Tags: regex, sublime-text-2

SublimeText's regex parser doesn't seem to work like others.

If I write `(.*{50, 51})+`, or `(.*{50,})+`, or `(.*{50})+`, it doesn't grab sets of 50 characters. I think it tries to match the { as a literal.

How can I use the min/max occurrance syntax in Sublime?

Answer (score 1):

Ah it was the * that got me. How silly of me. It works without the double repetition specifier.